# PHP Array - Remove unwated key + retain data

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I exactly remove an unwanted parent from an xml node and keep the data intact? Something like array shift.
For example, I have an array

```
            [LineItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [LineItem] => Array
                                (
                                    [Description] => iPhone
                                    [Quantity] => 1
                                    [UnitAmount] => 101.0000
                                    [AccountCode] => 200
                                    [TaxAmount] => 0.0000
                                    [LineAmount] => 101.0000
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [LineItem] => Array
                                (
                                    [Description] => Flat Shipping Rate
                                    [Quantity] => 1
                                    [AccountCode] => 200
                                    [UnitAmount] => 5.0000
                                    [LineAmount] => 5.0000
                                )

                        )

                )
```

How do I exactly remove LineItems[0] and LineItems[1] and push the LineItem array to the left? I'm looking for something like this:

```
  [LineItems] => Array
                (
                    [LineItem] => Array
                                (
                                    [Description] => iPhone
                                    [Quantity] => 1
                                    [UnitAmount] => 101.0000
                                    [AccountCode] => 200
                                    [TaxAmount] => 0.0000
                                    [LineAmount] => 101.0000
                                )

                        )

                   [LineItem] => Array
                                (
                                    [Description] => Flat Shipping Rate
                                    [Quantity] => 1
                                    [AccountCode] => 200
                                    [UnitAmount] => 5.0000
                                    [LineAmount] => 5.0000
                                )

                        )
```

Also, when converting an array like :

```
Array
(
    [Invoices] => Array
        (
......something....
)
)
```

When converting to XML, the xml will output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Invoices>
  </Invoices>
</root>
```

How do I actually remove the root?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am looking for something like this -> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3R08esvr

Comment: That's not possible, you can't have duplicate keys...

Comment: As onetrickpony said, you can't have duplicate keys like that. Would you like to use the `Description` as the keys?

Comment: It's possible via simplexml and iteration, but as you're looking for arrays, you perhaps should make yourself comfortable with what arrays are firsthand: http://php.net/array - like others have already commented, not possible. What to say?

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmparr=[];
array_push($tmparr,$arr[LineItems][0][LineItem],$arr[LineItems][1][LineItem]);
unset($arr[LineItems][0],$arr[LineItems][1]);
foreach($tmparr as $key=>$val){
$arr[LineItems][]=$val;
};
unset($tmparr);
```

i guess...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($my_array['Invoices']['LineItems'] as & $lineItem) 
   $lineItem = $lineItem['LineItem'];
```

About the XML question, you can try this function (based on [a comment on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#101949)):

```
function array2xml($array, $root_element_name = 'root') 
{ 
    if (count($array) == 1) {
        $root_element_name = reset(array_keys($array));
        $array = reset($array);
    }
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}/>"); 

    function xml_builder($node, $array) { 
            foreach($array as $key => $value) { 
                if (is_array($value)) { 
                    if (is_integer($key) && count($value) == 1) {
                        $key = reset(array_keys($value));
                        $value = reset($value);
                    }
                    $child = $node->addChild($key); 
                    xml_builder(& $child, $value); 
                } else { 
                    $node->addChild($key, $value); 
                } 
            }
    }; 
    xml_builder(& $xml, $array); 

    return $xml->asXML(); 
} 

print htmlentities(array2xml($my_array));
```